# Does the latest Android support bluetooth printing profiles?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

One of our existing app currently prints using wi-fi. I need to enable it to print using bluetooth. According to the developer guide Android bluetooth api implements only Headset and A2DP profiles.

1) Is there anyway we can use the BluetoothProfile interface to implement printing profile BPP? If yes, how can this be done?

2) Is there any reliable thirdparty bluetooth sdk which does the job?

Thanks in advance for your valuable guidance.